# Interview Question about SQL group by and having

Tags: sql, group-by, having, having-clause

This problem is from the following

https://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/advanced-sql-interview-questions-and-answers/

Assume we have two tables:

```
Salesperson 
ID  Name    Age Salary


Orders
Number  order_date  cust_id salesperson_id  Amount
```

The question is following:

We want to retrieve the names of all salespeople that have more than 1 order from the tables above. You can assume that each salesperson only has one ID. I would probably also assume that names are all distinct.

My answer was this.

```
select Name from 
salesperson S inner join Orders O 
on S.ID=O.salesperson_id 
group by Name 
having count(number) >=2
```

However, the given answer is following:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Orders inner join Salesperson
On Orders.salesperson_id = Salesperson.ID
GROUP BY salesperson_id, NAME
Having count(salesperson_id) > 1
```

If name and salesperson_id is one to one, is there any reason we have to add salesperson_id into the group by statement here? Also, if name and salesperson_id relationship is just one to one, wouldn't count(salesperson_id) be always 1 if we group by salesperson_id, name?

I was a bit confused about this, and I was wondering if anybody encountered this problem before and found this weird as well.

Comment: Both queries output the same result. The only reason to put  `salesperson_id` in the `group by` clause is if you want it to be in `select` too.

Comment: @rad I disagree.  `salesperson_id` is most likely being added to `GROUP BY` to deal with the possibility that two salespeople happen to have the same name. I

Comment: @Tim Beigeleisen OP assumes that all names are uniques too. Therefore there is no difference between the two `group by` clauses.

Comment: _You can assume that each salesperson only has one ID_ but not the name, As Tim said the combination of name and Id make them unique so we need both in group by clause.

Comment: But what about count(salesperson_id)? Wouldn't it always be 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your solution and the accepted one are functionally identical, except for the `GROUP BY` clause.

The likely reason why the accepted solution is aggregating both by `Name` and `salesperson_id` is that it could be the case that two or more salespeople happen to have the same name.  Should this occur, your query would report only a single name, but with aggregate results from more than one salesperson.  But, the combination of `salesperson_id` and `Name` should always be unique.

Other than this, I actually prefer your version, and I would start joining from the `salesperson` table out to the `Orders` table.

Comment: My biggest gripe was the posted answer was that what if a (NAME, salesperson_id) pair has more than 1 order numbers? If we apply group by Name, salesperson_id and filter by having count(salesperson_id) > 1, then I think we will miss out on those cases. That's why I thought my answer was correct, not what was posted.

Comment: @user98235 I think you might be confused about how `HAVING` works, and there is nothing wrong with your logic.  The `COUNT` function counts any non `NULL` value as 1.  So, your logic is just saying give me all salespeople with 2 or more orders; this is correct.

Comment: I'm thinking of following cases:  let's assume we have two rows  (Jim, 1, 10), (Jim, 1, 12), which is just a triplet of name, salespersonid, ordernumber. Jim clearly has more than 1 order, but if we do select name, salespersonid from table group by name, salespersonid having count(salespersonid) > 1
then wouldn't count(salespersonid)=1 be for Jim? However, if we do count(odernumber)>1, then Jim will be selected.

Comment: No, it would assign a count of 2 to Jim.  Again, `COUNT` just counts non `NULL` values, it knows nothing of the business logic behind the column you are asking it to count.